# declaring destructor affects object's lifetime?

Tags: c++

Going back to C++ after 15 years and playing around with the *Expression Templates* concept described in "Discovering Modern C++" book I came across a behaviour I'm not able to explain (although my C++ knowledge was very basic back then, so I hope this is something obvious).

Here's the minimal example (I know it's long, but that's the best I could do to illustrate the problem):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename T>
class container {
private:
    T data;

    template<typename Src>
    void copy_from(Src& that) {
        data = that.get();
    }

public:

    using value_type = T;

    inline T get() const {
        auto p= data;
        return p;
    }

    void set(T v) {
        data = v;
    }

    template<typename Src>
    container& operator=(const Src& that) {
        copy_from(that);
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename Src>
    container(const Src& that){
        copy_from(that);
    }

    container() = default;

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& s, container<T> const & matrix) {
        s << std::endl << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << matrix.data <<std::endl;
        return s;
    }
};

template <typename A1, typename A2>
class sum {
    using mytype = sum<A1, A2>;
public:
    sum(const A1 & a1, const A2 & a2):
    a1(a1), a2(a2) {
        std::cout <<"constructing sum ("<<(long)this<<") with a1 = " << (long)&a1 << " and a2 = " <<(long)&a2 << std::endl;
    }

    // (1)
    // ~sum() {}

    using value_type = std::common_type_t <typename A1::value_type, typename A2::value_type>;

    inline value_type get() const {
        std::cout <<"getting elem from sum ("<<(long)this<<") with a1 = " << (long)&a1 << " and a2 = " <<(long)&a2 << std::endl;

        auto x = a1.get();
        auto y = a2.get();
        auto p = x + y;
        return p;
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout <<"I'm a sum ("<<(long)this<<") with a1 = " << (long)&a1 << " and a2 = " <<(long)&a2 << std::endl;
    }

private:
    const A1 &a1;
    const A2 &a2;
};

template <typename A1, typename A2>
sum<A1, A2> inline operator+ (const A1& a1, const A2& a2) {
    return {a1, a2};
}

template <typename A>
class apply {

public:
    using value_type = typename A::value_type;
    using function_type = std::function<value_type(value_type)>;

    apply (const A& a, const function_type & f):
    a(a), f(f) {std::cout <<"constructing apply ("<<(long)this<<") with a = " << (long)&a<< std::endl; }

    inline value_type get() const {
        std::cout <<"address of apply's member obj is " << (long)&a << ", type is " <<typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
        auto p = f(a.get());
        return p;
    }

private:
    const A &a;
    const function_type & f;
};

template<typename T>
class applicator {
public:

    using value_type = T;
    using function_type = std::function<value_type(value_type)>;

    applicator( const function_type & f): f(f) { }

    template<typename A>
    // (2)
    inline apply<A> operator() (A param) {
        std::cout <<"address of () param is " << (long)&param << ", type is " <<typeid(param).name() <<": ";
        param.print();
        apply<A> op { param, f };
        return op;
    }

private:
    const function_type & f;
};

double square(double x) {
    return x*x;
}

int main() {

    std::cout << "--- Creating variable" << std::endl;
    container<double> W;
    std::cout << W;

    std::cout << "--- Setting values in the variable" << std::endl;
    W.set(4);

    std::function<double(double)> my_fun = square;
    applicator sq { my_fun };

    std::cout << "decltype(W) is_trivially_copyable? " << std::is_trivially_copyable_v<decltype(W)> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "decltype(W+W) is_trivially_copyable? " << std::is_trivially_copyable_v<decltype(W+W)> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "decltype(sq(W+W)) is_trivially_copyable? " << std::is_trivially_copyable_v<decltype(sq(W+W))> << std::endl;

    std::cout << "--- Performing function on addition" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex;

    auto r = sq(W+W);

    std::cout << "Created var r with address " <<(long)&r<<", type: " <<typeid(r).name() <<std::endl;

    std::cout << "--- Copying to container and printing out results" << std::endl;
    std::cout << r << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and here's the output:

```
--- Creating variable

0.00000000
--- Setting values in the variable
decltype(W) is_trivially_copyable? 1
decltype(W+W) is_trivially_copyable? 1
decltype(sq(W+W)) is_trivially_copyable? 1
--- Performing function on addition
constructing sum (7ffeefbff3a0) with a1 = 7ffeefbff508 and a2 = 7ffeefbff508
address of () param is 7ffeefbff388, type is 3sumI9containerIdES1_E: I'm a sum (7ffeefbff388) with a1 = 7ffeefbff508 and a2 = 7ffeefbff508
constructing apply (7ffeefbff398) with a = 7ffeefbff388
Created var r with address 7ffeefbff4e0, type: 5applyI3sumI9containerIdES2_EE
--- Copying to container and printing out results
address of apply's member obj is 7ffeefbff388, type is 3sumI9containerIdES1_E
getting elem from sum (7ffeefbff388) with a1 = 7ffeefbff4c8 and a2 = 7ffeefbff3b0

0.00000000
```

The parameter in `// (2)` is passed by value, so the temporary object gets destroyed when `operator()` exists and so the `a` member of `apply` class references garbage. That makes sense to me. But if we uncomment the destructor definition from class `sum` (see `// (1)`), then the result is correct and the final `sum` object references correct `container`s. Why?

if we keep the destructor commented out and change `// (2)` to passing by reference, everything seems to work correctly. Is it because const reference extends the lifetime of the temporary object returned by `operator+`? If so, why `apply<A>` constructor does not extend the lifetime of the `param` object from `operator()`? The apply class keeps reference to the object passed in the constructor.

Comment: Point of advice: Expression templates and `auto` are not compatible. You *will* run into dangling references very quickly. Even libraries like Eigen have that [exact same problem](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The parameter in `// (2)` is passed by value, so the temporary object gets destroyed when `operator()` exists and so the `a` member of `apply` class references garbage. That makes sense to me.

Correct.  In

```
inline apply<A> operator() (A param)
```

The returned `apply<A>` has a reference to `param` which has gone out of scope so you have a dangling reference and using it is undefined behavior.

> But if we uncomment the destructor definition from class `sum` (see `// (1)`), then the result is correct and the final `sum` object references correct `container`s. Why?

Again, undefined behavior.  Just because the code shouldn't work doesn't mean it cant.  Since you have undefined behavior it is even allowed to give you the "correct" results.

> if we keep the destructor commented out and change `// (2)` to passing by reference, everything seems to work correctly. Is it because const reference extends the lifetime of the temporary object returned by `operator+`?

This is because you have bound a reference to an object from the call site.  That means when the function returns to the call site the reference it has still refers to the valid object you passed to it.  This means your reference still points to a valid object and you have defined behavior.

> If so, why `apply<A>` constructor does not extend the lifetime of the `param` object from `operator()`? The apply class keeps reference to the object passed in the constructor.

A `const &` only extends the lifetime of a function local temporary.

```
{ // start of some scope
    const int& foo = function_that_returns_temporary();
} // end of some scope
```

The above is legal and the compiler will extend the lifetime of the returned value to the end of the scope.  having

```
struct Foo
{
    const int& bar
    Foo(const int& ref) : bar(ref)
};
```

Does not extend the lifetime of what `ref` refers to.  If whatever `ref` refers to goes out of scope before the `Foo` object that was created with it is destroyed then that object is left with a dangling reference.